# Mounting Fedora 25 LVM partition returns unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, mount, lvm

I have been trying to mount a partition (`/dev/sda4` is this detail helps) to `/mnt` so I can chroot into it from Ubuntu 16.04. But whenever I try to mount it I get the error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

Now I have tried installing `lvm2` with APT. I have also tried starting the `lvm2-lvmetad` service and socket, but I still get this same error. I have seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/766141/93125) but it was not helpful to me for two reasons:

- Firstly, it seems to pertain to a system with multiple LVM2 partitions where in there is a need to distinguish between their labels. I have only one LVM2 partition and its label is `fedora`.
- Secondly, it provides no real details on how to rename a partition group (merely says "using `vgrename`", as opposed to giving a specific command to do this).

If it helps here is my partition table (which I got by running `fdisk /dev/sda -l`):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 70714BA5-A85F-4BEB-BA64-79D0AD3EB7B8

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 1154484223 1153433600  550G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1920108544 1953523711   33415168   16G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  1154484224 1867401215  712916992  340G Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

**EDIT:**
`pvscan` returns:

```
  PV /dev/sda4   VG fedora          lvm2 [339.94 GiB / 12.00 MiB free]
  Total: 1 [339.94 GiB] / in use: 1 [339.94 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

while `lvscan` returns:

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/fedora/root' [339.93 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: Did you try `pvscan` and `lvscan` to see if the LVM partition is recognized? Please add the output to your question.

Comment: OK, I added the output to the question. It seems to me like they are recognizing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mount the LVM logical disk, not the LVM physical disk. In your specific case, you want to mount `/dev/fedora/root`.

```
 fsck -p /dev/fedora/root
 mount /dev/fedora/root /mnt
```