# Error: mount lvm2 is not a block device

Tags: boot, partitioning, lvm

gparted sees the partition 'lvm2', however Dolpin (File Manager) does not see the drive and therefore not mounted.

i reading
"You used the exact same name (ubuntu-vg) for your new volume group as the old volume group. You must give them unique names. You can rename one of the groups using vgrename and its UUID."
[askubuntu.com mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member)

Find the UUID with vgdisplay and then rename the volume group:

```
sudo vgdisplay
[sudo] password for administrator: 
  /dev/sde: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sde: open failed: No medium found
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               new_lvm2
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <931,01 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              238338
  Alloc PE / Size       244 / 976,00 MiB
  Free  PE / Size       238094 / 930,05 GiB
  VG UUID               96qWN4-1W7c-Kwvx-zLeA-9u83-h18g-qBZYAH
```

```
vgrename <VG UUID> new_name
sudo vgrename 96qWN4-1W7c-Kwvx-zLeA-9u83-h18g-qBZYAH new_lvm3
[sudo] password for administrator: 
  /dev/sde: open failed: No medium found
  Processing VG new_lvm2 because of matching UUID 96qWN4-1W7c-Kwvx-zLeA-9u83-h18g-qBZYAH
  Volume group "96qWN4-1W7c-Kwvx-zLeA-9u83-h18g-qBZYAH" successfully renamed to "new_lvm3"
```

gparted sees the partition 'lvm3', however Dolpin (File Manager) does not see the drive and therefore not mounted.

next i tried this: [mount unknown filesystem type 'lvm2_member'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member#comment1930108_1078061) . means:

```
sudo bash
vgrename 96qWN4-1W7c-Kwvx-zLeA-9u83-h18g-qBZYAH new_lvm4
modprobe dm-mod
vgchange -ay
lvscan
# Create the mount point directory:
sudo mkdir /mnt/new_lvm4/
# Mount: 
mount /dev/new_lvm4/root /mnt/new_lvm4/
```

Some information about comand before:

- [LVM Infos german](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/LVM_Grundkonfiguration)
  vgdisplay show information to VG (Physical volume)
- [Modprobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modprobe)
- [vgchange -a n is deaktivated the VG - Infos i german](http://www.linuxhaven.de/dlhp/HOWTO-test/DE-LVM-HOWTO-3.html)

```
# vgchange -ay
  /dev/sde: open failed: No medium found
  /dev/sde: open failed: No medium found
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "new_lvm4" now active

# lvscan
  /dev/sde: open failed: No medium found
  ACTIVE            '/dev/new_lvm4/swap_1' [976,00 MiB] inherit
# sudo mkdir /mnt/new_lvm4/
# mount /dev/new_lvm4/root /mnt/new_lvm4/
mount: /mnt/new_lvm4: special device /dev/new_lvm4/root does not exist.
root@administrator-kdeNeon:/home/administrator# 
# mount /dev/new_lvm4 /mnt/new_lvm4/
mount: /mnt/new_lvm4: /dev/new_lvm4 is not a block device.
root@administrator-kdeNeon:/home/administrator#
```

For this error i reading here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30637/mount-error-is-not-a-block-device

and tried:

```
# mount --bind /dev/new_lvm4 /mnt/new_lvm4/
root@administrator-kdeNeon:/home/administrator#
```

however Dolpin (File Manager) does not see the drive and therefore not mounted.

any idea?

Comment: i tried `sudo mount /dev/new_lvm4/swap_1 /mnt/new_lvm4 mount: /mnt/new_lvm4: unknown filesystem type 'swap'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you on matrix: There is no such option to mount a swap device.
If you did not see any data LV in your VG then there is nothing to recover.