# Mount LUKS encrypted Disk from old OS

Tags: mount, encryption, luks

Hey wonderful Ask Ubuntu Community,

on my new Laptop I want to access the  LUKS encrypted data on some old hard drives which where used in my old computers.

**Long story short:** Unfortunately it seems I am not able to activate the volumegroup using `sudo vgchange -ay` getting `device busy`:

```
sudo vgchange -ay
device-mapper: create ioctl on vgubuntu-root LVM-SelHt8NeMlYbL68cnLF0t64jwxkcrLURglB0Elk4hnQizRDiXDKJjQBITSJN7Sfx failed: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
device-mapper: create ioctl on vgubuntu-swap_1 LVM-SelHt8NeMlYbL68cnLF0t64jwxkcrLURaV8upU0JXaoUg20OQV21tWbNnIsjwMna failed: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
```

**Long story long:**

I attached the old disk containing the OS and LUKS data via SATA-USB Adapter.
It gets reconised and Ubuntu asks me for the password.
I enter the LUKS Password and the boot partition gets mounted.
In Drives I see the disk (sda) and the LUKS Partition (sda6) is unlocked and a LVM2 partition of the same size is present.
I use `sudo lvscan` to scan for logical volumes and for sda I get:

```
sda                                             8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   512M  0 part  /media/Username/1EDD-E50C
├─sda2                                          8:2    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda5                                          8:5    0   731M  0 part  /media/Username/9a46f5fa-e8e7-4bb7-b073-5ed7005e6ad2
└─sda6                                          8:6    0 231,7G  0 part
  └─luks-9f6c23d7-8fa3-4a3b-a979-d12bb83edec4 253:3    0 231,7G  0 crypt
```

Now I use "sudo lvscan" to scan for logical volumes:

```
inactive          '/dev/vgubuntu/root' [230,66 GiB] inherit
inactive          '/dev/vgubuntu/swap_1' [976,00 MiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/root' [<930,37 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/swap_1' [976,00 MiB] inherit
```

Ok I see my LUKS data seems inactive.
I try to activate it with `sudo vgchange -ay` getting `device busy` error mentioned above:

```
sudo vgchange -ay
device-mapper: create ioctl on vgubuntu-root LVM-SelHt8NeMlYbL68cnLF0t64jwxkcrLURglB0Elk4hnQizRDiXDKJjQBITSJN7Sfx failed: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
device-mapper: create ioctl on vgubuntu-swap_1 LVM-SelHt8NeMlYbL68cnLF0t64jwxkcrLURaV8upU0JXaoUg20OQV21tWbNnIsjwMna failed: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
```

I try `ls -al /dev/mapper/` and get:

```
insgesamt 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     140 Mai 15 09:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root    5340 Mai 15 09:57 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Mai 15 08:58 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mai 15 09:57 luks-9f6c23d7-8fa3-4a3b-a979-d12bb83edec4 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mai 15 08:58 nvme0n1p3_crypt -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mai 15 08:58 vgubuntu-root -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mai 15 08:58 vgubuntu-swap_1 -> ../dm-2
```

So I try to mount the luks partition with `sudo mount /dev/dm-3 /media/Username/SSD_Crypt` and get `unknown filesystem type "LVM2_member`:

```
mount: /media/carsten/SSD_Crypt: unbekannter Dateisystemtyp „LVM2_member“.
```

From here I am lost, since I verified with `sudo apt-get install lvm2` lvm2 is installed.

---

I also gathered some **additional info** but I am not getting through it:

Output of `sudo pvscan`:

```
PV /dev/mapper/luks-9f6c23d7-8fa3-4a3b-a979-d12bb83edec4   VG vgubuntu        lvm2 [231,65 GiB / 36,00 MiB free]
PV /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt                             VG vgubuntu        lvm2 [<952,64 GiB / <21,32 GiB free]
```

Output of `sudo vgscan`:

```
Found volume group "vgubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
Found volume group "vgubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
```

To me it seems the volumegroup of the old disk is the same es the one of the Disk in the new System and therefore can not be activated. But I do neither know if this is the cause of the problem nor how to solve it.

---

**To repeat my goal:** I want to access the LUKS encrypted Data from an old Disk which was used to boot in an old computer on a new Ubuntu computer which also uses LUKS encryption. Probably I am mixing something up as my understanding of LUKS is limited. I would really appreciate if you could give me some hints or even better steps to reproduce to mount my old LUKS encrypted data.

Comment: My guess is it's that logical volume management that makes things complicated. If you know which of the partitions (sda1, sda2, sda5, sda6) you want to mount, try opening it directly using something like `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdax crypt` and then mounting /dev/mapper/crypt somewhere, but before entering any password when you connect the drive.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I just tried what you proposed and it turns out I get the same error 'unknown Filesystem type "LVM2_member": mount: /media/Username/SSD_Crypt: unbekannter Dateisystemtyp „LVM2_member“.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. It was as I guessed: The volumegroups of the new OS Harddisks and the old OS Harddisks being the same (vgubuntu) was blocking the activation of the old data on the new system.

You need to change the volumegroup as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member) and than you can activate the volumegroup and simply mount:

1. get the UUID of the old volumegroup

> sudo vgdisplay

2. rename it to a new name

> sudo vgrename  new_name

3. apply

> modprobe dm-mod

4. activate volumegroups

> vgchange -ay

5. scan

> lvscan

6. mount

> mount /dev/new_name/root /mnt/data/

Comment: I think there's a formatting problem with point 3.

Comment: Changed. Thanks.

Comment: How could this possible be the "correct answer" when most of the command line arguments in the steps are missing?