# Unable to mount to /dev/sda3 (lvm2)

Tags: 22.04, lvm

Being an amateur, I tried to mount the /dev/sda3 partition to a mount point after installing the latest LTS of Ubuntu Server

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /home/xxxx/bake-buddy
mount: /home/xxxx/bake-buddy: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
```

I found this article and tried to follow the answer steps there [mount unknown filesystem type 'lvm2_member'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member)

```
    root@tez:/home/xxxx# lvscan
      ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu/ubuntu-lv' [235.42 GiB] inherit
root@tez:/home/xxxx# mount /dev/ubuntu/ubuntu-lv /home/xxxx/bake-buddy
root@tez:/home/xxxx# < no error >
```

But when I view the /home/xxxx/bake-buddy directory, it's the same as the root directory contents, so I have something hoarked up. Can you tell from the below displays what I need to clean up...or should I just reinstall?

```
root@tez:/home/xxxx# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               235.42 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              60268
  Alloc PE / Size       60268 / 235.42 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               XXXX-etc etc

root@tez:/home/xxxx# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                   7:0    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop1                   7:1    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1695
loop2                   7:2    0  79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop3                   7:3    0   103M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23541
loop4                   7:4    0  49.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17883
sda                     8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                  8:3    0 235.4G  0 part
  └─ubuntu-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 235.4G  0 lvm  /

root@tez:/# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  1.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G  7.5G   86G   9% /
tmpfs                              7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  246M  1.6G  14% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

EDIT: Based on the first comment, followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621, ran the following steps:

```
sudo pvscan
  PV /dev/sda3   VG ubuntu          lvm2 [235.42 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [235.42 GiB] / in use: 1 [235.42 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
sudo vgscan --mknodes
 Found volume group "ubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
sudo vgchange -ay
1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu" now active
sudo lvscan
 ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu/ubuntu-lv' [235.42 GiB] inherit
 sudo mount /dev/ubuntu/ubuntu-lv /home/xxxx/bake-buddy
<no error>
```

did a list of the /home/xxxx/bake-buddy contents and it's the root directory listing, which is not what I want. Looking more and more like I should just reinstall

Comment: You used LVM or volumes. The one partition is just a container for your volume(s). I do know LVM, but you cannot mount the partition, you mount the volume. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621
For mounting encrypted see first few lines:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu