# Disconnected Hard Drive Still Listed and Will Not Mount

Tags: mount, hard-drive, 22.04, encryption

I have a 3 Terabyte hard drive I took out of an old NAS. I ended up using it as a distro testing drive, as it was old and I didn't want to risk losing data to drive failure. I installed Pop!_OS with full disk encryption, but ended up using a folder on it for backups.

I did a large file transfer last night and unmounted the drive. I connected it this morning and tried to open the encryption but got an error: "Could not mount /dev/sdd4. File exists."

I am using Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS.

Comment: What is the filesystem on which Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS is running (*the root partition `/`*) and the filesystem on the 3 TB hard disk?

Comment: Ubuntu Studio is running on ext4, with a seperate home partition that is also ext4. The 3TB drive is LVM2 pv.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used cryptsetup to open the encryption on the hard drive, tried to mount, and got an `unknown filesystem type` error. Then I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member). Thanks to @nork for the detailed answer!